# Chrome Extension getting content of meta property on page and passing back to extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've been working on a new Chrome Extension that pulls the content property from meta tags and displays them in the popup.js window. I've experimented with a few different types of coding, but nothing works. Currently, settings include:

manifest.json

```
"permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "storage", "<all_urls>"],
```

popup.js

```
let metaContent = $('#id-string') // div to display in popup
// event listener to click on button in popup to grab meta tag
popupButton.on('click', function(metaContent) {
    let tags = $('meta[property="keywords"]').attr('content')
    metaContent.html(tags)
}
```

It looks like this may be a popular problem.

Comment: See [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)

Answer (score 0):

you need to write the grab meta code in a content script, not in popup.js